# Compare values from two columns with same values in a table and set a different column as the Select

Tags: mysql

SO i have columns id, first_name, manager_id
I want the manager_id find its own value in ID and select that id's row's first_name
So if the column is

```
|id| first_name|manager_id|
|1 | Jack      | 1   | 
|2 | John      | 1   |
|3 | Jerry     | 2   |
```

As a SELECT it should display as

```
|1 | jack      | null|
|2 | john      | Jack|
|3 | Jerry     | John|
```

I have tried

```
SELECT
CASE
   WHEN manager_id = employeedb.id THEN first_name
      END AS Manager
```

But that just compares it with the id of the same row, i need it to compare to all of the rows
and many other things. Id really appreciate the help

Comment: You can `JOIN` a table to itself. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self `JOIN` with an `IF` condition to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.first_name, 
  IF(b.id = a.id, NULL, b.first_name) as manager_name
FROM sample a
INNER JOIN sample b ON a.manager_id = b.id
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/xPxKbWFE).

**Result**:

| id | first_name | manager_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | null |
| 2 | John | Jack |
| 3 | Jerry | John |